# How to concatenate pointer arrays

Tags: c, memory, concatenation

I'm writing a program where I need to concatenate two arrays.

For example if I had:

```
  int max =100;
  char *append = "Hello";
  char *pStr = malloc(max);
```

How would I concatenate `append` onto `pStr`?

Comment: `pStr` currently does not contain a string, so you cannot append onto it. Can you give an example of what it should look like afterwards?

Comment: Are you confusing copy and concatenate? There are functions to do both -- `strcpy` to copy and `strcat` to concatenate.

Answer (score 2):

Use can choose between these two:

```
char *pStr = malloc(max);
char* str1 = "Hello ";
char* str2 = "Wor";
char* str3 = "ld";
strcpy(pStr, str1);
strcat(pStr, str2);
strcat(pStr, str3);
```

or

```
char *pStr = malloc(max);
char* str1 = "Hello ";
char* str2 = "Wor";
char* str3 = "ld";
pStr[0] = '\0';
strcat(pStr, str1);
strcat(pStr, str2);
strcat(pStr, str3);
```

in your example

```
strcpy(pStr, append);
```

or

```
pStr[0] = '\0';
strcat(pStr, append);
```

`strcpy` doesnt need the `\0`. It just copies the *destination string(plus the '\0')*.
`strcat` concatenates the *destination string* to the *source string*. Source **must** be null terminating thats why the `pStr[0] = '\0'`.

`max` must be sufficient to hold all the strings plus the terminating character `\0`

valter

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Once it's allocated, you can't change the size.

What you gonna do is allocate a new space (large enough to hold both), and copy them into it.

```
char* str1 = "Hello";
char* str2 = "World";
char* con = (char*) calloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1, sizeof(char));
strcpy(con, str1);
strcpy(con + strlen(str1), str2);
fprintf("%s\n", con); // "HelloWorld"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
*pStr = 0; //to initialize it
strcpy(pStr, append);
```

Comment: op wants concatenation, not a copy.

Comment: Even if this is what OP wanted, `*pStr = 0;` has no effect becaus eyou immediately copy over it.

Comment: @deeiip And copying a string to an empty string is not equal to concatenate?